# What is the species that Worf fights on the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, worf

In the below picture, this is an alien we see Worf fighting on a regular basis.  Is there any reference to what it is, where it came from (somewhere near Q'onos I assume) or any contact made between these species and UFOP, or is it some random thing Worf has made to fight for fun?

[image: Skeletor I am told]

Comment: Just saying that I'd prefer a canonical answer, not the obvious one of 'ugly skullhead'!

Comment: The canon answer is that they're "Hulking ogre-like...Skull-faced...Alien...monsters"

Comment: Dax also used the same alien It has been established that the Klingons have taken several SLAVE races
These could be one of those races Maybe a race used as conon foder to make other races ripe for conquest
It would not be two far fetch to think this is why the Klingons are so feaded
Drop these guys in to soften you up then swoop in for the kill
Lets not fotget the Remeans the Romulans used them the same way

Comment: I'll be disappointed if there isn't a novel somewhere that named them Skeletorians.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### They aren't named in-universe or outside.

The skull-headed monster appears in 4 episodes within the trek universe, each time in a "[Klingon Training Program](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon_calisthenics_program_holograms)". Evidently they're ***"Alien Warriors"..."from Klingon Mythology".***

DS9 [Way of the Warrior](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/474.txt) :

> "Worf is wielding a Klingon saber, fighting a **hulking ogre-like
>   monster** from Klingon mythology."

TNG [Where Silence Has Lease](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/128.txt) :

> As he rolls catlike to his feet, the massive form of an **ALIEN WARRIOR**
>   leaps onto his back bringing him back to the ground. The alien raises
>   a club-like weapon over his head and swings down at Worf's head.

TNG [New Ground](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/210.txt) :

> Alexander is wearing a small practice robe similar to the one we've
>   seen Worf use. He is fighting the **SKULL FACED ALIEN**, seen in previous
>   episodes, with Worf's bat'telh sword.

TNG : [The Emissary](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/146.txt)

> Then, seemingly from nowhere, a massive **ALIEN WARRIOR** springs into
>   view, charges at K'Ehleyr.

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

---

Out of universe, this article on Memory Alpha describes the origin of the Skull-faced Warrior. Evidently it's the same mask used for Skeletor in the 1987 flop "[Masters of the Universe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093507/)"

[image: Skeletor]

Comment: ...and now I can officially claim that Worf has fought Skeletor. +1.

Comment: Also, I think Worf's "mother" referred to them as "holodeck monsters" or something similar

Comment: So the Klingon equivalent of 'orcs': plentiful, honorless, and fun to kill.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine they're the same species that conquered the Klingons and stole/destroyed a bunch of their stuff. After all, what could be more honorable than defeating the first enemy to ever enslave the Klingon race, as far as we know at least.

> Following the theft of the Sword, numerous fake Shrouds were "discovered" over the years. A Vulcan expedition found the true Shroud among the remains of a ***Hur'q*** outpost in the Gamma Quadrant in 2372. Using the data provided by the Vulcans, Dahar master Kor launched a quest to find the Sword itself. He, along with Jadzia Dax and Worf, discovered the Sword in the same ***Hur'q*** outpost.
>
> <sub>[Memory Alpha, Sword of Kahless](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kahless)</sub>

It's important to note that any descriptions of the [Hur'q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hur%27q) are considered apocryphal according to the wiki. Though the wiki states, above the apocrypha section, that the Federation knows the DNA sequences for the Hur'q, meaning they would be relatively easy to replicate in a holosuite.

Comment: Not incompatible with the script calling them "monsters from Klingon mythology".  According to that Memory Alpha page, the Klingons last saw the Hur'q in the 14th century A.D., time enough for things to get scrambled.  Kahless, in the 9th century, had certainly well and truly become mythology by the time of Star Trek.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a canon book, the novel "*Kahless*" describes him as a Pandrilite. Don't deny yourself a good read because a book isn't canon!  **:)**

> *Actually, it was an adaptation of a program Worf himself had used when
>   he first arrived on the Enterprise.*
>
> *Of course, a Klingon had been inserted **in place of a [Pandrilite](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Pandrilite)** and it
>   was restricted to Level One, whereas Worf had bumped it up to Level
>   Three at times. But otherwise, it was pretty much the same.*

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the alien above isn't a pandrilite. Various book sources (Fortune's Light, Captain's table, Stargazer, Valiant) describe them as blue-skinned, with intelligent eyes, long-fingered hands and oversized heads. These baddies have none of these features.

Comment: Also, this would clash with the established canon (script) that they're mythological.